# If statement by comparing player input and a list and timer not working as intended

Tags: python, list, time, list-comparison

```
wordlist = [['annoyed'], ['bulb'], ['fetch'], ['name'], ['noise'], ['wistful'], ['sparkle'], ['grain'], ['remind'], ['shocking'], ['productive'], ['superficial'], ['craven'], ['plate'], ['cup'], ['hat'], ['summer'], ['chilly'], ['crowd'], ['tiresome'], ['amount'], ['previous'], ['creepy'], ['insidious'], ['foolish'], ['trot'], ['well-groomed'], ['meat'], ['bottle'], ['van'], ['teeny-tiny'], ['edge'], ['knot'], ['disarm'], ['store'], ['shaggy'], ['furniture'], ['provide'], ['puzzled'], ['grubby'], ['texture'], ['cart'], ['tangy'], ['load'], ['stone'], ['plastic'], ['argument'], ['hop'], ['painstaking'], ['tense'], ['educate'], ['fearless'], ['fierce'], ['profuse'], ['addition'], ['staking'], ['attract'], ['boundary'], ['hurt'], ['delay'], ['tangible'], ['awesome'], ['ruthless'], ['guttural'], ['follow'], ['zephyr'], ['mute'], ['abandoned'], ['yak'], ['best'], ['continue'], ['stem'], ['cake'], ['multiply'], ['riddle'], ['delightful'], ['vulgar'], ['neck'], ['rampant'], ['complete'], ['certain'], ['plant'], ['organic'], ['reach'], ['tenuous'], ['chubby'], ['nut'], ['wiry'], ['knife'], ['first'], ['learned'], ['allow'], ['glass'], ['beef'], ['madly'], ['knowledgeable'], ['prepare'], ['compare'], ['perform'], ['rhetorical'], ['hover'], ['exciting'], ['adventurous'], ['cakes'], ['miniature'], ['deafening'], ['snail'], ['shy'], ['delirious'], ['hypnotic'], ['gigantic'], ['heady'], ['pen'], ['cent'], ['pump'], ['wide-eyed'], ['brief'], ['trains'], ['light'], ['order'], ['communicate'], ['bizarre'], ['flavor'], ['thirsty'], ['fasten'], ['black-and-white'], ['divergent'], ['gusty'], ['halting'], ['decide'], ['file'], ['ossified'], ['melt'], ['turkey'], ['avoid'], ['film'], ['null'], ['orange'], ['language'], ['adaptable'], ['cars'], ['eyes'], ['reject'], ['shave'], ['odd'], ['bruise'], ['cows'], ['curtain'], ['whirl'], ['wail'], ['deep'], ['mere'], ['grease'], ['phobic'], ['run'], ['scientific'], ['clear'], ['one'], ['wealthy'], ['pigs'], ['inquisitive'], ['toothsome'], ['memorise'], ['flap'], ['demonic'], ['cats'], ['injure'], ['jellyfish'], ['crow'], ['flame'], ['window'], ['rock'], ['chew'], ['pedal'], ['scared'], ['amuck'], ['hour'], ['wacky'], ['thoughtful'], ['used'], ['temporary'], ['fluttering'], ['pass'], ['ski'], ['zealous'], ['rhythm'], ['sea']]


#the word list is longer. shortened it for easier readability purposes. 

start = input("Press enter to start")
start_time = time.time()
time_limit = 10

start = input("Press enter to start")
while True:
    #timer function
    current_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = current_time - start_time
    time_left = time_limit - elapsed_time

    #chooses a random word from list
    x = random.choice(wordlist)
    print(*x, "\n", sep = '')
    print(x)
    typed_word = input("type the word:")
    if typed_word == x:
        print("~correct~")
    else:
        print("~wrong~")

    if elapsed_time >= time_limit:
        print("time elapsed " + str(int(elapsed_time)))
        break
```

Hi everyone, I just started out on a new project that tests your typing speed but ran into some issue i just can't seem to solve. First, the timer seems to go over the 10 second limit as shown below in the image url. Second, I can't seem to make to program verify the word the player inputs. It always outputs ~wrong~ as shown below in the image url. Each time I print a word from a list, it always prints with the [''] which makes the aesthetics of the game look unpleasant. So, I first thought the problem was due to me removing the [''] by using `print(*x, "\n", sep = '')`
so, I tried alternative inputs to see whether if I can get `typed_word == x`. However, it seems futile as shown in the image url. Also the reason why i asked the program to print(x) was so I could verify exactly what was being pulled from the list. Please I really need some help!!!

Image of the outputs:

https://ibb.co/n0KY70Y

Comment: `if typed_word == x:` This comparison will never be true, because `typed_word` is a plain string and `x` is a list that _contains_ a string, such as `['annoyed']`.  A list can never equal a string.

Comment: Change `wordlist` to a list of strings.  Right now it's a list of lists, where each of the inner lists contains a single string (which isn't very useful).

Comment: You should check `if typed_word == x[0]:` as `x` will always be a list. You are picking a list from within a list using the random function `x = random.choice(wordlist)`. If your list was just a list of strings instead of a list of lists, then you could have checked for `x`. Here, the code has to be `x[0]`

Comment: Also you dont have to convert `input` into a string. In python, input is by default a string.

Comment: Please add time_limit values for time exceeding problem so member can help and for Checking input simply do `typed_word == x[0]`

Comment: If you changed your wordlist to look something like this, your code will work fine. `wordlist = ['annoyed', 'bulb', 'fetch']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two lines that need code change to check for the correct word are :

```
#input is by default a string. so you don't have to convert it to str()
typed_word = input("type the word:")

#wordlist is a list of list. 
#random.choice(wordlist) will give you a list from the list
#so you need to check typed_word against a list of length 1
if typed_word == x[0]:
```

Here's the full code for your reference. The only two lines I changed are the ones above and setting the values for `start_time` and `time_limit`

```
import random
import time

wordlist = [['annoyed'], ['bulb'], ['fetch'], ['name'], ['noise'], ['wistful'], ['sparkle'], ['grain'], ['remind'], ['shocking'], ['productive'], ['superficial'], ['craven'], ['plate'], ['cup'], ['hat'], ['summer'], ['chilly'], ['crowd'], ['tiresome'], ['amount'], ['previous'], ['creepy'], ['insidious'], ['foolish'], ['trot'], ['well-groomed'], ['meat'], ['bottle'], ['van'], ['teeny-tiny'], ['edge'], ['knot'], ['disarm'], ['store'], ['shaggy'], ['furniture'], ['provide'], ['puzzled'], ['grubby'], ['texture'], ['cart'], ['tangy'], ['load'], ['stone'], ['plastic'], ['argument'], ['hop'], ['painstaking'], ['tense'], ['educate'], ['fearless'], ['fierce'], ['profuse'], ['addition'], ['staking'], ['attract'], ['boundary'], ['hurt'], ['delay'], ['tangible'], ['awesome'], ['ruthless'], ['guttural'], ['follow'], ['zephyr'], ['mute'], ['abandoned'], ['yak'], ['best'], ['continue'], ['stem'], ['cake'], ['multiply'], ['riddle'], ['delightful'], ['vulgar'], ['neck'], ['rampant'], ['complete'], ['certain'], ['plant'], ['organic'], ['reach'], ['tenuous'], ['chubby'], ['nut'], ['wiry'], ['knife'], ['first'], ['learned'], ['allow'], ['glass'], ['beef'], ['madly'], ['knowledgeable'], ['prepare'], ['compare'], ['perform'], ['rhetorical'], ['hover'], ['exciting'], ['adventurous'], ['cakes'], ['miniature'], ['deafening'], ['snail'], ['shy'], ['delirious'], ['hypnotic'], ['gigantic'], ['heady'], ['pen'], ['cent'], ['pump'], ['wide-eyed'], ['brief'], ['trains'], ['light'], ['order'], ['communicate'], ['bizarre'], ['flavor'], ['thirsty'], ['fasten'], ['black-and-white'], ['divergent'], ['gusty'], ['halting'], ['decide'], ['file'], ['ossified'], ['melt'], ['turkey'], ['avoid'], ['film'], ['null'], ['orange'], ['language'], ['adaptable'], ['cars'], ['eyes'], ['reject'], ['shave'], ['odd'], ['bruise'], ['cows'], ['curtain'], ['whirl'], ['wail'], ['deep'], ['mere'], ['grease'], ['phobic'], ['run'], ['scientific'], ['clear'], ['one'], ['wealthy'], ['pigs'], ['inquisitive'], ['toothsome'], ['memorise'], ['flap'], ['demonic'], ['cats'], ['injure'], ['jellyfish'], ['crow'], ['flame'], ['window'], ['rock'], ['chew'], ['pedal'], ['scared'], ['amuck'], ['hour'], ['wacky'], ['thoughtful'], ['used'], ['temporary'], ['fluttering'], ['pass'], ['ski'], ['zealous'], ['rhythm'], ['sea']]


#the word list is longer. shortened it for easier readability purposes. 

start = input("Press enter to start")

#I started the clock here as soon as you press the enter key
start_time = time.time()

#i set the time to 10.0 seconds
time_limit = 10.0

while True:
    #timer function
    current_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = current_time - start_time
    time_left = time_limit - elapsed_time

    #choses a random word from list
    x = random.choice(wordlist)
    print(*x, "\n", sep = '')
    print(x)
    typed_word = input("type the word:")
    if typed_word == x[0]:
        print("~correct~")
    else:
        print("~wrong~")

    if elapsed_time >= time_limit:
        print("time elapsed " + str(int(elapsed_time)))
        break
```

**The output is:**

```
Press enter to start
pedal

['pedal']
type the word:pedal
~correct~
amuck

['amuck']
type the word:pedal
~wrong~
stone

['stone']
type the word:amuck
~wrong~
chubby

['chubby']
type the word:chubby
~correct~
rhythm

['rhythm']
type the word:rhythm
~correct~
nut

['nut']
type the word:nut
~correct~
time elapsed 14
```

Comment: The comparison wasn't the problem.  The problem is that the word list contains a useless extra list level.  It should just be a list of strings.  This answer just perpetuates a design mistake.